# Unity. Как сделать систему обхода препятствий в 2D?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня есть игра 2D, где несколько персонажей, которых я могу выбирать и ими ходить. Проблема возникает при их столкновении. Чтобы такого не происходило, мне нужно сделать систему обхода, чтобы персонажи замечали препятствие (объект или другого плеера) и обходили его на некотором расстоянии по кратчайшему пути слева или справа. Передвигаются они к точке ПКМ. Передвигаю их c rigidbody.MovePosition. NavMesh только в 3d сейчас как я понимаю работает.  Подскажите, что использовать, что загуглить.

Comment: Есть 2D реализация NavMesh. https://github.com/h8man/NavMeshPlus

Comment: @ТёмаKornishon Спасибо. Но уже пробовала так, юнити пишет, что версия устаревшая, ошибки появляются и не работает. Устанавливала по разным видео, именно по указанной ссылке, скачивала зип файл. Стала искать дальше инфу, в интернете также пишут, что на версии юнити 2022.3 уже не поддерживается NavMesh в 2д. Поэтому возник вопрос есть ли альтернативные варианты. Или возможно я делаю что-то не так?